# How to import data from .nc format into array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a file which contains the data and is in .nc format. I want to import this data into an array.How do I do so?

Comment: You need to have a parser of some sort, I don't know python so cannot give you any more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `netCDF4`?

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
your_file = 'yourfile.nc'
data = Dataset(your_file, mode='r')
```